# How to Launch an Exe at User Level from a Higher Level

Tags: c++, winapi, uac

I would like a process to always run at the user level. Either when it is launched by the installer (custom, not msi), which runs as at the administrator level, or when a user logs on. Looking around, I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to have 2 processes. One is normal user and it launches elevated/admin process. Then admin process can use IPC to ask normal user process to do things.

If you have no normal user process, then [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/18/10468726.aspx) documents:

> Going from an unelevated process to an elevated process is easy. You can run a process with elevation by [passing the runas verb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vistacompatteam/archive/2006/09/25/771232.aspx) to Shell­Execute or Shell­Execute­Ex.
>
> Going the other way is trickier. For one thing, it's really hard to munge your token to remove the elevation nature properly. And for another thing, even if you could do it, it's not the right thing to do, because the unelevated user may be different from the elevated user.
>
> The solution here is to go back to Explorer and ask Explorer to launch the program for you. Since Explorer is running as the original unelevated user, the program (in this case, the Web browser) will run as Bob. This is also important in the case that the handler for the file you want to open runs as an in-process extension rather than as a separate process, for in that case, the attempt to unelevate would be pointless since no new process was created in the first place. (And if the handler for the file tries to communicate with an existing unelevated copy of itself, things may fail because of UIPI.)
>
> Okay, I know that Little Programs are not supposed to have motivation, but I couldn't help myself. Enough jabber. Let's write code. (Remember that Little Programs do little or no error checking, because that's the way they roll.)
>
> ```
> #define STRICT
> #include <windows.h>
> #include <shldisp.h>
> #include <shlobj.h>
> #include <exdisp.h>
> #include <atlbase.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> void FindDesktopFolderView(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
> {
>  CComPtr<IShellWindows> spShellWindows;
>  spShellWindows.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows);
>
>  CComVariant vtLoc(CSIDL_DESKTOP);
>  CComVariant vtEmpty;
>  long lhwnd;
>  CComPtr<IDispatch> spdisp;
>  spShellWindows->FindWindowSW(
>      &vtLoc, &vtEmpty,
>      SWC_DESKTOP, &lhwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH, &spdisp);
>
>  CComPtr<IShellBrowser> spBrowser;
>  CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider>(spdisp)->
>      QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser,
>                   IID_PPV_ARGS(&spBrowser));
>
>  CComPtr<IShellView> spView;
>  spBrowser->QueryActiveShellView(&spView);
>
>  spView->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
> }    
>
> void GetDesktopAutomationObject(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
> {
>  CComPtr<IShellView> spsv;
>  FindDesktopFolderView(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spsv));
>  CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispView;
>  spsv->GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spdispView));
>  spdispView->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
> }
> ```
>
> The Get­Desktop­Automation­Object function locates the desktop folder view then asks for the dispatch object for the view. We then return that dispatch object in the form requested by the caller. This dispatch object is a Shell­Folder­View, and the C++ interface for that is IShell­Folder­View­Dual, so most callres are going to ask for that interface, but if you are a masochist, you can skip the dual interface and talk directly to IDispatch.
>
> ```
> void ShellExecuteFromExplorer(
>     PCWSTR pszFile,
>     PCWSTR pszParameters = nullptr,
>     PCWSTR pszDirectory  = nullptr,
>     PCWSTR pszOperation  = nullptr,
>     int nShowCmd         = SW_SHOWNORMAL)
> {
>  CComPtr<IShellFolderViewDual> spFolderView;
>  GetDesktopAutomationObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spFolderView));
>  CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispShell;
>  spFolderView->get_Application(&spdispShell);
>
>  CComQIPtr<IShellDispatch2>(spdispShell)
>     ->ShellExecute(CComBSTR(pszFile),
>                    CComVariant(pszParameters ? pszParameters : L""),
>                    CComVariant(pszDirectory ? pszDirectory : L""),
>                    CComVariant(pszOperation ? pszOperation : L""),
>                    CComVariant(nShowCmd));
> }
> ```
>
> The Shell­Execute­From­Explorer function starts by getting the desktop folder automation object. We use the desktop not because it's particularly meaningful but because we know that it's always going to be there.
>
> As with the desktop folder view, the Shell­Folder­View object is not interesting to us for itself. It's interesting to us because the object resides in the process that is hosting the desktop view (which is the main Explorer process). From the Shell­Folder­View, we ask for the Application property so that we can get to the main Shell.Application object, which has the IShell­Dispatch interface (and its extensions IShell­Dispatch2 through IShell­Dispatch6) as its C++ interfaces. And it is the IShell­Dispatch2::Shell­Execute method that is what we really want.
>
> And we call IShell­Dispatch2::Shell­Execute with the appropriate parameters. Note that the parameters to IShell­Dispatch2::Shell­Execute are in a different order from the parameters to Shell­Execute!
>
> Okay, let's put this inside a little program.
>
> ```
> int __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
> {
>  if (argc < 2) return 0;
>
>  CCoInitialize init;
>  ShellExecuteFromExplorer(
>     argv[1],
>     argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : L"",
>     argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : L"",
>     argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : L"",
>     argc >= 6 ? _wtoi(argv[5]) : SW_SHOWNORMAL);
>
>  return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> The program takes a mandatory command line argument which is the thing to execute, be it a program or a document or a URL. Optional parameters are the parameters to the thing being executed, the current directory to use, the operation to perform, and how the window should be opened.
>
> Open an elevated command prompt, and then run this program in various ways.
>
> - scratch http://www.msn.com/
>     Open an unelevated Web page in the user's default Web browser.
> - scratch cmd.exe "" C:\Users "" 3
>     Open an unelevated command prompt at C:\Users, maximized.
> - scratch C:\Path\To\Image.bmp "" "" edit
>    
>     Edit a bitmap in an unelevated image editor.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. It works nicely. Unfortunately you have to be careful not to call FindWindowSW too soon. It will return S_FALSE with NULL pointer if called before the Desktop has been started. We see this a lot when a new user is being setup on a Windows 10 machine. Our code fires before it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody is always looking for going around the other way.  Anyhoo, this [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/SubvertingVistaUAC.aspx) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know which user you want to run as, and have their password, the [CreateProcessWithLogonW Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431(VS.85).aspx) will do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many hacky ways to do this (Use the taskscheduler, inject into explorer.exe etc)

The only way to get the correct user (The one that started your program before UAC elevation (This might not be the same user as the shell/"login"/"session owner")) is to have the installer run two instances of itself, one "outer" instance that is not elevated, it mostly just starts the other instance by starting itself with ShellExecute[Ex] with the runas verb. When it comes time to start the medium/low level process, the elevated instance by some form of IPC tells the outer instance to start the new process.

It is a pain in the neck to implement, I would recommend just **not** having a run checkbox at the end of your installer.

Comment: It is nice, but not "ONLY" (correct) way. You can call IShell­Dispatch2::Shell­Execute without injecting.

Comment: @Alexander: IShell­Dispatch2 will execute as the same user as Explorer.exe which might not be the "correct" user and will not work at all on server core with cmd.exe shell...

Answer (score 0):

similar to what Bill said, you can also use CreateProcessAsUser() API to do that.

1. First use LogonUser() and get an access token for the user that the process needs to run as . Here if the user belongs to administrators group (then you will get a split token if you pass the LOGON_FLAG as LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE). So if you need the elevated administrator token pass the flag as LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH.
2. With the token obtained above, you can call CreateProcessAsUser() passing the commandline and parameters.