# How to force an app to not be run as administrator

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, uac

Is it possible to disable run as administrator for an app alowing it just to be run as local user.

Comment: @elyashiv Looks like either or both of Windows Vista or Windows 7, since no other version of Windows supports UAC, which as a tag on this question.

Comment: Please look a this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051415/how-to-launch-an-exe-at-user-level-from-a-higher-level?rq=1)

Comment: exit if the running user is in administrators group.

Comment: But what if the local user is in admninistrator group but it isn't running app via run as administrator.

Comment: @H.B., you can be in administrator group and run apps without elevated privileges

Comment: You could take a look at the DropMyRights source code and have your program relaunch itself (or another program) if it has administrator privileges.  That'd be similar to how some web browsers and PDF readers sandbox themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can prevent starting the process as administrator; however, you can check if it is executing with elevated privileges, and exit if it's the case.

```
    static bool IsRunningWithElevatedPrivileges()
    {
        IntPtr hToken;
        int sizeofTokenElevationType = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));
        IntPtr pElevationType =
            Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeofTokenElevationType);

        if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TokenQuery, out hToken))
        {
            uint dwSize;
            if (GetTokenInformation(hToken,
                TokenInformationClass.TokenElevationType, pElevationType,
                (uint)sizeofTokenElevationType, out dwSize))
            {
                TokenElevationType elevationType = (TokenElevationType)Marshal.ReadInt32(pElevationType);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pElevationType);

                switch (elevationType)
                {
                    case TokenElevationType.TokenElevationTypeFull:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        //case TokenElevationType.TokenElevationTypeLimited:
                        //case TokenElevationType.TokenElevationTypeDefault:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr processHandle,
        uint desiredAccess,
        out IntPtr tokenHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetTokenInformation(
        IntPtr tokenHandle,
        TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass,
        IntPtr tokenInformation,
        uint tokenInformationLength,
        out uint returnLength);

    const UInt32 TokenQuery = 0x0008;

    enum TokenElevationType
    {
        TokenElevationTypeDefault = 1,
        TokenElevationTypeFull,
        TokenElevationTypeLimited
    }

    enum TokenInformationClass
    {
        TokenUser = 1,
        TokenGroups,
        TokenPrivileges,
        TokenOwner,
        TokenPrimaryGroup,
        TokenDefaultDacl,
        TokenSource,
        TokenType,
        TokenImpersonationLevel,
        TokenStatistics,
        TokenRestrictedSids,
        TokenSessionId,
        TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
        TokenSessionReference,
        TokenSandBoxInert,
        TokenAuditPolicy,
        TokenOrigin,
        TokenElevationType,
        TokenLinkedToken,
        TokenElevation,
        TokenHasRestrictions,
        TokenAccessInformation,
        TokenVirtualizationAllowed,
        TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
        TokenIntegrityLevel,
        TokenUIAccess,
        TokenMandatoryPolicy,
        TokenLogonSid,
        MaxTokenInfoClass
    }
```